# OnClick in PreferenceFragment Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I am displaying my "Settings" screen through a class that extends PreferenceFragment.  I need to know when a particular setting is clicked so that I can handle the Intent to launch at runtime, as opposed to declaring in xml like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
      android:title="@string/terms_conditions"
      android:summary=""
      android:layout="@layout/settings_item">
       <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
             android:data="http://www.somecompany.com/m/EULA.aspx" />
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

I need to fire a different Intent depending on other variables involved.

So, what I need is to know when the user clicks the "Terms and Conditions" within the settings fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the class in which you need to know about config changes implement

```
SharedPreferences.onSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

and install it as a listener in your SharedPreferences via

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Then handle the changes is

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged()
```

The relevant documentation is about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)